# Cordova Install ITunes failed

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I installed Cordova for Visual Studio 2013.

It all went fine except that ITunes failed.

I went to reinstall and selected 'Repair'
The installer started to download all the parts again,
taking a long time to fetch the Android SDK and other parts.

This is a concern since I already installed them.  I just want to install
the ITunes.  I understand I can install the parts separately but how do 
I make VSCordova aware of the location of ITunes.

Comment: If you are not explicitly going to be using iTunes in your application you don't need to worry about installing it.  If you do intend using it then my I am sorry but my comment is not much use,

Comment: Well it is part of the installation of Visual Studio Cordova.  I am not sure what it is used for, since building for iOS takes part on a Mac communicating thru the node plugin for remote debugging.  When I repaired the installation, it went to install all the parts again.  I rolled it back, and then when I started VS.net and opened a cordova app it prompted me to install it.  A standard install worked.

Comment: I didn't bother installing iTunes and I have had no problems build my applications.  I haven't tried creating an IOS build as yet, but have built and deployed to multiple Andriod tablets and phones and Windows 8 tablets and Windows phone.

Comment: This is what I am unclear about.  If building on an Apple is required for iOS version, then really iTunes needs to be installed on the Mac, and is not required on Windows.  I have only a 128GB SSD drive so I don't like to install anything unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is not required if you're only doing Android and Windows development.  And for iOS development, iTunes is only required if you want to deploy to an iOS device tethered to your Windows development machine. VS also supports deploying to an iOS device connected directly to your Mac.

If iTunes is installed on your PC, you don't need to do anything special to make VS Cordova Tools aware of its location.  If figures that out itself.

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering what WebSocket4Net does, apparently is only required if developing for Windows 7, but I don't know why SignalR could not do the same as it has alot of backward compatibility.  Also wondering where SQLLite is used?  I know it is a compact database, but what is its function in building multi-device hybrid apps.